# Collapsing together duplicate rows with synonyms

Tags: r, dplyr

If my data looks something like this:

```
species1     species2    info1    info2
Loro         Parrot      3        NA 
NA           Parrot      NA       7
Osprey       NA          NA       89
Sparrow      Finch       NA       19
Sparrow      NA          27       NA
Mallard      Duck        69       16
Mallard      NA          NA       NA
NA           Swift       25       NA
```

And i want to merge it together like this:

```
species1     species2    info1    info2
Loro         Parrot      3        7
Osprey       NA          NA       89
Sparrow      Finch       27       19
Mallard      Duck        69       16
NA           Swift       25       NA
```

How could i do it, tanking into account that i need to keep the NA records?

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use similar approach from the previous post, but in a different way i.e. first create a named vector from the 'species' columns'.  Use that to replace the values in first 'species1' column, `coalese` with the second one to do a grouping and then do the `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
nm1 <- df1 %>% 
      select(species1, species2) %>% 
      na.omit %>% 
      deframe
df1 %>% 
     group_by(species = coalesce(nm1[species1], species2)) %>% 
     summarise(across(everything(), ~ .[complete.cases(.)][1])) %>% 
     select(-species)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  species1 species2 info1 info2
  <chr>    <chr>    <int> <int>
1 Mallard  Duck        69    16
2 Sparrow  Finch       27    19
3 Loro     Parrot       3     7
4 <NA>     Swift       25    NA
5 Osprey   <NA>        NA    89
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(species1 = c("Loro", NA, "Osprey", "Sparrow", 
"Sparrow", "Mallard", "Mallard", NA), species2 = c("Parrot", 
"Parrot", NA, "Finch", NA, "Duck", NA, "Swift"), info1 = c(3L, 
NA, NA, NA, 27L, 69L, NA, 25L), info2 = c(NA, 7L, 89L, 19L, NA, 
16L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may group by one column and `fill` the `NA` values in other one to get the pairs, after which take `sum` of the values grouping by both the species column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(species2) %>%
  fill(species1) %>%
  group_by(species1) %>%
  fill(species2) %>%
  group_by(species2, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup

#  species1 species2 info1 info2
#  <chr>    <chr>    <int> <int>
#1 Loro     Parrot       3     7
#2 Mallard  Duck        69    16
#3 Osprey   NA           0    89
#4 Sparrow  Finch       27    19
#5 NA       Swift       25     0
```